# TF-IDF: TDFIDFVectorizer to consider a specific compound noun

Tags: python, tokenize, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

I'm trying to determine in which documents the term 'Artificial Intelligence' is a key concept using tf-idf. I'm quite new to all of this and have managed to get it working for single words such as AI following [worked example for TF-IDF with Scikit-Learn](https://melaniewalsh.github.io/Intro-Cultural-Analytics/05-Text-Analysis/03-TF-IDF-Scikit-Learn.html).
I'm using TfidfVectorizer in the following way:

```
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(input='filename', stop_words='english')
tfidf_vector = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(text_files)
tfidf_df = pd.DataFrame(tfidf_vector.toarray(), index=text_titles, columns=tfidf_vectorizer.get_feature_names())
tfidf_slice = tfidf_df[['ai','people','human','data','minority','nhs','power','technology','threaten','china']]
tfidf_slice.sort_index().round(decimals=2)
tfidf_df.stack().reset_index()
tfidf_df = tfidf_df.rename(columns={0:'tfidf', 'level_0': 'document','level_1': 'term', 'level_2': 'term'})
tfidf_df.sort_values(by=['document','tfidf'], ascending=[True,False]).groupby(['document']).head(10)
```

I can access terms and documents via

```
top_tfidf = tfidf_df.sort_values(by=['document','tfidf'], ascending=[True,False]).groupby(['document']).head(10)
top_tfidf[top_tfidf['term'].str.contains('ai')]
```

However, my approach only works for 'AI' but splits 'Artificial Intelligence' into 'artificial' and 'intelligence'.
Based on looking at other examples on here, my understanding is that I should be able to look at compound nouns by changing the n-gram setting. Another spontaneous guess was  to do this via enforcing a rule by which if words that follow each other are capitalised (as in names or Artificial Intelligence) then these should be read as one unit.

Any help as to how to make this focus on 'AI' as well as 'Artificial Intelligence' would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you managed to successfully extract the importance of desired words/expressions in a document using `tf-idf` please share the solution with us. Thank you in advance